# splice array from data

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to splice an array but index doesn't work

```
var kode_pelayanan = [];
function deleteKodePelayanan(index){
    kode_pelayanan.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(kode_pelayanan);
}
```

i tried in console and array for `kode_pelayanan` is. This array get from input

```
kode_pelayanan array ["LB1", "LB2", "LHA01", "LHA02"]
```

but when i run function `deleteKodePelayanan()` and splice `LB2`. the value is

```
["LB2", "LHA01", "LHA02"]
```

Comment: how do you get index ?

Comment: `deleteKodePelayanan()` would be equivalent to `splice(undefined, 1)` or `splice(0, 1)` which means start at index `0` and delete *one* element. Which as your results so is correct. Try `deleteKodePelayanan(1)` and see what happens. Also `deleteKodePelayanan("LB2")` would be coerced into a `0` as well. Same problem.

Comment: the index is a numeric value. To get your results, you'd have to pass in 0 (or a value that casts to 0 (like undefined))

Comment: Show where you call this function and what value you pass to it. We can't help without all the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Try some validation on the index before splice.

```
function deleteKodePelayanan(index){
  index = parseInt(index,10);
  if (isNaN(index)) {
    // index is not a number
    return;
  } else if (!(index in kode_pelayanan)) {
    // index is a number but the value isn't set
    return;
  }
  kode_pelayanan.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Why so many if/else? `index >= 0` is simpler and readable. Err that is if you use `indexOf` first.

Comment: You're right undefined is a valid value so I changed it to look for the index instead. I wanted to do validation of the existence of the index. May not be needed with splice, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the train of thought I think you want to know how to remove an element from an array based on the values of the elements *not* based on the index. The answer is two steps. Find the index then use splice to remove it.

Use `indexOf` to find the index first.

```
var kode_pelayanan = ["LB1", "LB2", "LHA01", "LHA02"];

function deleteKodePelayanan(value){
    var index = kode_pelayanan.indexOf(value);
    if (index >= 0) {
      kode_pelayanan.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(kode_pelayanan);
}

deleteKodePelayanan("LB2"); // => ["LB1", "LHA01", "LHA02"]
```